# Evaluating expressions of random length

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is based on a problem [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/arithmetic-expressions/problem):

> **Input Format**
>
> The first line contains a single integer *n* denoting the number of
>   elements in the list. The second line contains *n* space-separated
>   integers *a1, a2, a3, ...* denoting the elements of the list.
>
> **Output Format**
>
> Print a single line containing the required expressoin. You may insert
>   spaces between operators and operands.
>
> **Note**
>
> - You are not allowed to permute the list.
> - All operators have the same precedence and are left-associative

In my code below I can make it work using nested `for` loops when I know the length of the input, but my input may have 5 or 50 or 500 elements and I won't know that until run-time. The depth of the nested `for` loops would be `len(arr)-1`, but maybe there's a better way to approach this problem.

As I see it, I need to:

- generate `ops_combos` for `input_ints` of random length (without using the `permutations` lib, per hackerrank instructions)
- evaluate the expressions
- and return the first expression that evaluates `True`.

Any suggestions?

```
import operator
ops = { "+": operator.add, "*": operator.mul, "-": operator.sub } # etc.

opers = ['+','*','-']
arr = [55, 3, 45, 33, 25] # needs to work for any length of arr

# Generate every len(arr)-1 combo of the 3 symbols (include repetition)
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        for k in range(3):
            for l in range(3):                
                x = ops[ opers[i] ]( arr[0], arr[1] )   # first number (0), first operator  (i), second number (1)
                x = ops[ opers[j] ]( x,      arr[2] )   # x,                second operator (j), third number  (2)
                x = ops[ opers[k] ]( x,      arr[3] )   # x,                third operator  (k), fourth number (3)
                x = ops[ opers[l] ]( x,      arr[4] )   # x,                fourth operator (l), fifth number  (4)

                if x % 101 == 0:
                    print (arr[0], opers[i], arr[1], opers[j], arr[2], opers[k], arr[3], opers[l], arr[4])
```

Comment: The instruction is not to permute the list, not to avoid using permuation functions on operators, which you have to do

Comment: Thank you for the edit, @OlivierMelançon. I see I misunderstood the instructions. Regarding using permutations on the operators, am I correct that instead I need to use _combinations_ so that I can allow repetitions?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon, ignore the question in my comment above. I see in your solution below that you didn't use itertools's permutations or combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link your provided does not disallow `itertools`, what it means is that you are not allowed to change the order of the provided numbers.

That being said, you will need to use `itertools.product` or your own implementation of `product` as getting the solution requires testing all possible combinations of operators.

The function `find_operations` returns a generator of all solutions. This allows to recover either the first solution with `next` or to unpack all of them.

### Code

```
from itertools import product, chain
from operator import add, sub, mul

def apply(numbers, operations):
    """Return the result of applying a list of operations to the list of numbers"""
    ans, *numbers = numbers
    for num, op in zip(numbers, operations):
        ans = op(ans, num)

    return ans

def find_operations(numbers):
    """Return the equation as string that satisfies the res % 101 == 0"""

    # Pair operations and their symbol to later format the result
    operations = {add: '+', sub: '-',  mul: '*'}

    # Loop over all combinations of operations and break when one satisfies
    for ops in product(operations, repeat=len(numbers) - 1):
        if apply(numbers, ops) % 101 == 0:
            # The following lines are just formatting and are not the main focus
            ops = [operations[op] for op in ops]
            nums = [str(x) for x in numbers]

            yield ' '.join(chain(*zip(nums, ops), nums[-1:]))
```

### Example

```
solutions = find_operations([22, 79, 21])

print(next(solutions))
```

### Output

```
22 + 79 * 21
```

Comment: This ignores operator precedence. It evaluates `22 + 79 * 21` as `(22 + 79) * 21` which is 0 mod 101 but `22 + (79 * 21)` is 65 mod 101. I can't see the problem so I can't tell if that is acceptable.

Comment: @DanD. The question specifically asks to ignore operator precedence

Comment: The given code does evaluate from left to right but the question does not.

Comment: @DanD. You need to read the link. I'll edit the question so people do not have to click it.

Comment: @DanD. Here it is done, you can read the lines I extracted from the question that indicate that all operations have the same precedence

Comment: @OlivierMelançon, this works great! I tested it on several sets of input, now I'm stepping through it to figure out how it works. Many thanks for your clear and thorough answer.

Comment: @neigedoi My pleasure. If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted so future user can find it more easily.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon, this code seems to return the last tested case even if it does not satisfy the test. I think that moving the last 3 lines of code into the if block in place of the break would fix this.
        if apply(numbers, ops) % 101 == 0:
            ops = [operations[op] for op in ops]
            nums = [str(x) for x in numbers]
            return ' '.join(chain(*zip(nums, ops), nums[-1:]))

Comment: @neigedoi I did so because from the question "he only gave lists of integers for which an answer exists". Although, you are right that there is no reason not to catch the case where there is no solution. I updated the solution so it returns a generator. This naturally returns an empty generator if there is no solution and allows to generalize if you need more than one solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not using permutation lib does not seem very reasonable to me. But you can make the equivalent of your nested loops by using generators:

```
opers = ['+','*','-']
arr = [55, 3, 45, 33]

def iterate(previous_iterator):
    for previous_list in previous_iterator:
        for oper in opers:
            yield [oper] + previous_list


operator_iterator = [[]]
for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
    operator_iterator = iterate(operator_iterator)

print(list(operator_iterator)) 
# [['+', '+', '+'], ['*', '+', '+'], ['-', '+', '+'], ['+', '*', '+'], ['*', '*', '+'], ['-', '*', '+'], ['+', '-', '+'], ['*', '-', '+'], ['-', '-', '+'], ['+', '+', '*'], ['*', '+', '*'], ['-', '+', '*'], ['+', '*', '*'], ['*', '*', '*'], ['-', '*', '*'], ['+', '-', '*'], ['*', '-', '*'], ['-', '-', '*'], ['+', '+', '-'], ['*', '+', '-'], ['-', '+', '-'], ['+', '*', '-'], ['*', '*', '-'], ['-', '*', '-'], ['+', '-', '-'], ['*', '-', '-'], ['-', '-', '-']]
```

And you can use this iterator to find your solutions:

```
import operator
ops = { "+": operator.add, "*": operator.mul, "-": operator.sub } # etc.

opers = ['+','*','-']
arr = [55, 3, 45, 33, 25] # needs to work for any length of arr

def iterate(previous_iterator):
    for previous_list in previous_iterator:
        for oper in opers:
            yield [oper] + previous_list
operator_iterator = [[]]
for i in range(len(arr) - 1):
    operator_iterator = iterate(operator_iterator)

for operator_list in operator_iterator:
    x = arr[0]
    for operator, value in zip(operator_list, arr[1:]):
        x=ops[operator](x, value)
    if x % 101 == 0:
        print(operator_list)

        # ['*', '+', '-', '+']
        # ['+', '-', '*', '-']
```